# Is the answer incorrect in the following tutorial

Tags: cassandra

In Example2 in the following tutorial, https://www.datastax.com/blog/2015/02/basic-rules-cassandra-data-modeling, the Primary Key is `(groupname, username)`. Shouldn't it be `((groupname),username)`?

The example says that:

> Note that the PRIMARY KEY has two components: `groupname`, which is the partitioning key, and `username`, which is called the clustering key.

I thought the primary keys are in their own  `()` and clustering keys follow outside the `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - it's correct syntax. First item in the list is always the partition key, so you can write it as `(groupname), username`, and as `groupname, username`. Explicit brackets are required if your partition key consists of the several columns.

Some people are always wrapping partition key into brackets, even if it consists of the one column.